# Any video tutorials for Named Pipes?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, named-pipes

Can someone point me to a video that teaches how to use named pipes in C# (.Net framework 3.5)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what's the context you are using NamedPipes communication for. But because you are using .Net 3.5 already, I would suggest using a WCF service to set up this communication, expose operation contracts that do the job and set the bindings to **netNamedPipesBinding** in the config.

Important thing is you can expose multiple endpoints with different types of bindings that use the same service methods.

You could host the service in a Windows Service service host, and it works really well.

Links:

- [Creating a basic WCF service -
  Screencast](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/cliff.simpkins/Endpoint-Screencasts-Creating-Your-First-WCF-Service/)
- [Excellent Video on WCF - getting the
  basics right - DNR TV Screencast](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122)
- [If you don't want to create a WCF service, then this article is for you](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/using-named-pipes-in-c-windows/) - No video